# why Valgrind's Heap Summary with more allocs and less frees when it's equal allocs and frees in my C program

Tags: c, memory-management

With valgrind, I find that there are more allocs and less frees in my C program. Although No memory leaks happened, I am confused with equal allocs and frees in my C program but unequal allocs and frees showed by valgrind.

From the Internet, I get such an answer:

This summary basically means that you didn't discard any pointers (set them to NULL) without first freeing associated allocated memory.

However, each `malloc` call has its corresponding `free` call in My C program. Does it means such unbalanced allocs and frees happen owing to functions of used library.

A Part of my Codes is as follow:

```
    char* input=readline("Lispy> ");      
    add_history(input);
    printf("No you're a %s\n", input);
    free(input);
```

Valgrind shows:

[image]

Comment: Where is the `malloc()`? Show all the code that is relevant.

Comment: malloc() is inside the readline function from library named editline. There is no malloc() in my code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I am confused with equal allocs and frees in my C program but unequal allocs and frees showed by valgrind.

Valgrind shows that you have made 195 allocs, of which 49 were freed, which leaves 146 memory blocks that were still allocated when program exited.

That blocks count towards "still reachable" part. That means that memory was allocated and not freed, but was still referenced (used) by program (i.e. there was still a pointer pointing to it), so it wasn't lost (leaked).

On the other hand, if block of memory was allocated, not freed but all pointers pointing to it were gone or reassigned, that would be a memory leak and would be reported in one of "lost" counters.

> However, each malloc call has its corresponding free call in My C
>   program. Does it means such unbalanced allocs and frees happen owing
>   to functions of used library.

That means that either that memory was allocated by external libraries or you have bug in your code. You could use `--leak-check-full`, as Valgrind suggest, to check this.

Comment: Thanks for your time! I got it now!